# Java/Unix: Can a Process sucessfully write a File if another Process tries to reads it inbetween

Tags: java, file, io, locking

The scenario (JAVA/UNIX):

Process A writes a File to Disk (using FileOutputStream)

Process B tries to read the same File while Process A is still writing (using FileInputStream)

questions:

- will Process A be able to successfully write the file to disk, even if Process B tries to read?
- what happens in Process B ? is the file locked? is there an IOException thrown? or can it read the incomplete file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Will Process A be able to successfully write the file to disk, even if Process B tries to read?

Yes.  It will be able to write the file correctly.  Reads do not interfere with a write ... on Linux.

> 2. What happens in Process B ? is the file locked? is there an IOException thrown? or can it read the incomplete file?

It will probably see an incomplete file.  (It might see a complete file ... if you are lucky.)

Linux doesn't lock files by default.  To get locking, both the reader and the writer need to make `flock(2)` syscalls.   In Java that maps to using `FileLock`.

No Java `IOException` will be thrown on UNIX / Linux / MacOS.  (Or on Android.)  You will only run into locking issues on Windows.

---

> Any hints appreciated.

Hint: you could just write a little test program and try it ....

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thank you. FileLocking was no option because the underlying filesystem is not under control of the OS (NFS). I also tried to provocate the case, but it hasn't worked out. How would you do it? I also wonder if i could find a official statment on your answer to Question #1 somewhere documented because i searched a lot and couldn't find a definitive answer. Regards

Comment: Yes. File locking on NFS is a problem. How would I do it? Use a separate file as a lock. That will work with NFS.  Definitive statement about read while writing?  I don't recall any.  If you want one, keep searching.